# identifier expected with combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

`cboMethod.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Method));`

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting payment with a specific method ...");
status = mollieClient.StartPayment(new Payment
{
amount = decimal.Parse(lblPrijs.Text),
method = Method.(cboMethod.SelectedItem.ToString()),
description = "Test payment",
redirectUrl = "http://www.lynx-automation.be/"
});
```

After the `Method.` is a little red line saying identifier expected. The selected item in my combobox should be that identifier. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access enum members dynamically like that. In this scenario you would probably want to use [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting payment with a specific method ...");
status = mollieClient.StartPayment(new Payment
{
    amount = decimal.Parse(lblPrijs.Text),
    method = (Method)Enum.Parse(typeof(Method), cboMethod.SelectedItem.ToString()),
    description = "Test payment",
    redirectUrl = "http://www.lynx-automation.be/"
});
```

Comment: @extreme4all You're not supposed to reply to an answer by editing it. That is what comments are for.

Comment: sorry, but i coudnt get the "yellow box" around the errors
>Error 1 'Mollie.Api.Method' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' 
>Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Enum.Parse(System.Type, string)' has some invalid arguments 
>Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Mollie.Api.Method' to 'System.Type'

Comment: @extreme4all I edited my answer 3 minutes ago to address that problem. I just forgot to add `typeof(...)`

Comment: sorry,
you can't do ";" it must be ","

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Mollie.Api.Method?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @extreme4all Looks like I missed a cast as well. Fixed it.